# Multi Tenant resolving to wrong tenant identifier EJB + JPA + HIBERNATE

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb, entitymanager, multi-tenant

I'm facing a problem implementing a Multi Tenant application with Hibernate 4.1.7 and EJB 3.1 using GlassFish 3.1.2 as Java EE Container
There's currently a class that implements org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver which identifies the logged in tenant fetching the logged in user with this code:

```
@Override
public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
    try {
        SessionContext context = ServiceLocator.locate(SessionEjbContext.class).getSessionContext();

        String userName = context.getCallerPrincipal().getName();

        AppLogger.info("current tenant identifier [" + userName + "]");

        return userName;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        AppLogger.info("erro lookup");
    }

    return "default";
}
```

The SessionContext.class is implemented as such

```
@Stateful
@SessionScoped
public class SessionEjbContext {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    public SessionContext getSessionContext() {
        return sessionContext;
    }
}
```

The id is then provided to the class that extends org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider which implements the method ConnectionProvider selectConnectionProvider(String tenantIdentifier) and must return a c3p0 ConnectionProvider object to use.

The real problem is this:
When the user user1 autheticates the system, the db connection is resolved ok.
But when the user2 authenticates, the method ConnectionProvider selectConnectionProvider(String tenantIdentifier) receives as parameter user1, and not user2, leading us to select the same database as user1.

The EntityManager is implemented with the PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED annotation, is that causing the problem? Maybe it's reusing information about the very first user!

Answer (score 0):

According to various posts, a JNDI lookup on stateful bean can create new instance of the bean. On the contrary, same bean is being returned for calls to resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier(). Please check the service locator and JNDI lookup methods.
It is a common behavior for JNDI libraries to cache instances of objects. As you had called JNDI lookup for SessionEjbContext corresponding to user1 , it might have been cached and being returned for all subsequent calls.